# Erlang atoms and ".."

Tags: erlang

This is output of erlang shell:

```
1> atom.
atom
2> next_atom.
next_atom
3> atom@erlang.
atom@erlang
4> 'atom in single quotes'.
'atom in single quotes'
5> atom = 'atom'.
atom
6> a.tom.
'a.tom'
7> a..tom.
* 1: syntax error before: '..'
```

When there is just one dot `.` within atom (line 6), I get no errors. However, when there is `..`, I get syntax error. Does `..` have some special meaning in Erlang or why do I get error when `.` works fine?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dots are not allowed as such in atoms, but a dot between two atoms: `'foo'.'bar'`,
is a compile time operator that concatenates the atoms to `'foo.bar'`.

This is an extension which was made to support the (still not officially
supported) Java-like package system. That's why it's not documented.

Comment: Afaik the syntax with '.' was also introduced to allow atoms as hostnames, i.e. bofh@home.com

Comment: This was asked several years ago, but it seems the newer versions of Erlang do not permit dots in atoms at all. I tried to paste an example, but it wasn't formatting correctly. `a.tom.` gives me `* 1: syntax error before: '.'`